# Refresh Token is missing in the JWT Response

Tags: azure, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to generate the OAUTH access token using the below end point with the below request. But unfortunately, I am not getting the refresh token in the response and all other details are displayed successfully in the response.

**End Point:**  oauth2/token

**Request:**

resource    : *`resource name`*,
client_id   : *`client_id`*,
grant_type  : **client_credentials**,
client_secret : *`client_secret`*

**Response:**

```
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_in": "3600",
"ext_expires_in": "0",
"expires_on": "1526380235",
"not_before": "1526376335",
"resource":  <<resource name>>
"access_token": <<generated token>>
```

Have I missed anything in this request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you authenticate with client credentials, you don't get a refresh token. You need to use the credentials each time.

What would the point be anyway?
If you got a refresh token, you would need to give Azure AD the credentials with it anyway to get the new token.

The point is you don't need a refresh token in this case.

Comment: Hi Juunas, Actually, I need to renew the access token using the refresh token for one of the scenario test. Whether do we have any other grant type which will give the refresh token?

Comment: Okay, let's step back a bit. If you only have the client credentials, you can get a new access token whenever you want with what you already did. But if you actually need to get an access token *for a user*, then you can get a refresh token for a user when authenticating them. What token are you trying to renew?

Comment: I need to test the below 2 scenarios

1. Request with Expired Access Token
2. Request with the renewed access token once the initially generated access token expires

For the first Scenario, I can test the API with the expired access token after the expiration time
For the Second Scenario, I assumed to use the refresh token concept to renew the access the token.

Can we achieve the second scenario with the refresh token ? else , I will regenerate the access token after the expiration time as per your comments

Comment: The second scenario you achieve by requesting a new access token with the client credentials, the same way you acquired the first one.

Comment: Yeah sure. I will regenerate the token after the expiration. In addition to this, can we revoke the access token in Azure?

Comment: No. An access token is valid until it expires. You can make additional checks in APIs you develop of course.